# Download not working on IOS chrome (Angular)

Tags: ios, angular

I have created a code to download PDF, this was working on all the devices. When using an IOS device it was downloading the file when I use the Safari browser, if I use chrome on an IOS device it was not downloading.

Below the code playground
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-blob-file-download-jrx4jf